# How make proc more effective?

Tags: tcl, polygon

There is a collection of vertices: [ x1 y1 x2 y2 .. xn yn ]

I would like to change the center of those coordinates. So I try:

```
proc changeCenter { vertices X Y } {
    set myList [list]
    foreach element $vertices {
        lappend myList [expr [lindex $element 0] + $X]
        lappend myList [expr [lindex $element 1] + $Y]
    }

 return $myList 
}
```

But its performance too slow.

How can I change above code to be more effective or maybe need to change  the representation of vertices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your changeCenter proc indicates the vertices collection is a list of pairs (`{{x1 y1} {x2 y2} ...}`), yet you are returning a flat list:

```
proc changeCenter { vertices deltaX deltaY } {
    set recentered [list]
    foreach vertex $vertices {
        lassign $vertex x y
        lappend recentered [list [expr {$x + $deltaX}] [expr {$y + $deltaY}]]
    }
    return $recentered 
}
```

If the vertices really are a flat list (`{x1 y1 x2 y2 ...}`) then read the list 2 elements at a time:

```
proc changeCenter { vertices deltaX deltaY } {
    set recentered [list]
    foreach {x y} $vertices {
        lappend recentered [expr {$x + $deltaX}] [expr {$y + $deltaY}]
    }
    return $recentered 
}
```

---

I haven't benchmarked it, but I suspect updating the vertices list in-place might be faster than appending to a new list:

```
proc changeCenter { vertices deltaX deltaY } {
    for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $vertices]} {incr i} {
        lset vertices $i 0 [expr {[lindex $vertices $i 0] + $deltaX}] 
        lset vertices $i 1 [expr {[lindex $vertices $i 1] + $deltaY}] 
    }
    return $vertices 
}
```

or

```
proc changeCenter { vertices deltaX deltaY } {
    for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $vertices]} {incr i 2} {
        lset vertices $i [expr {[lindex $vertices $i] + $deltaX}] 
        set j [expr {$i + 1}]
        lset vertices $j [expr {[lindex $vertices $j] + $deltaY}] 
    }
    return $vertices
}
```

depending on the structure of the vertices list as mentioned above.

---

Passing the vertices list by name would be faster still (avoid copying the data):

```
proc changeCenter { verticesName deltaX deltaY } {
    upvar 1 $verticesName v
    for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $v]} {incr i 2} {
        lset v $i [expr {[lindex $v $i] + $deltaX}] 
        set j [expr {$i + 1}]
        lset v $j [expr {[lindex $v $j] + $deltaY}] 
    }
    # no need to return a value
}
```

and call it with the variable *name*:

```
changeCenter vertices 1 2
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to do that is by bracing your expression:

```
proc changeCenter { vertices X Y } {
    set myList [list]
    foreach {x0 y0} $vertices {
        lappend myList [expr {$x0 + $X}]
        lappend myList [expr {$y0 + $Y}]
    }

    return $myList 
}
```

This has several benefits:

- The numbers don't have to be converted to a string and back.
- The expressions can be compiled.
- You don't get nasty rounding errors introduced by the string representation.
- It prevents injection of code that you don't want to execute.

See [this wiki entry](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10225) for further details.

And use foreach with more than one variable if you don't use nested lists as input.