# Why do Tcler suggest to brace your `expr`essions?

Tags: tcl

We can evaluate the two expression in two possible ways:

```
   set a 1
   set b 1
   puts [expr $a + $b ]
   puts [expr {$a + $b } ]
```

But why hate experienced Tclers the first one, and consider it as bad practice?
Does the first usage of `expr` has some security concern?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The "problem" with `expr` is that it implements its own "mini language", which includes, among other things, variable substitution (replacing those `$a`-s with their values) and command substitution (replacing those `[command ...]` things with the results of running `command`s), so basically the process of evaluating `expr $a + $b` goes like this:

1. The Tcl interpreter parses out four words — `expr`, `$a`, `+` and `$b` out of the source string. Since two of these words begin with `$`, variable substitution takes place so really there will be `expr`, `1`, `+`, and `2`.
2. As usually, the first word is taken to be the name of a command, and others are arguments to it, so the Tcl interpreter looks up a command named `expr`, and executes it passing it the three arguments: `1`, `+`, and `2`.
3. The implementation if `expr` then *concatenates* all the arguments passed to it interpreting them as strings, obtaining a string `1 + 2`.
4. This string is then *parsed again* — this time by the `expr` machinery, according to its own rules which include variable- and command substitutions, as already mentioned.

What follows:

- If you [brace your `expr`essions](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10225), like in `expr {$a + $b}`, grouping provided by those curly braces inhibits interpretation by the Tcl interpreter<sup>1</sup> of the script intended to be parsed by `expr` itself. This means in our toy example the `expr` command would see exactly one argument, `$a + $b`, and will perform substitutions itself.
- "Double parsing" explained above might lead to security problems.

  For example, in the following code

  ```
  set a {[exec echo rm -rf $::env(HOME)]}
  set b 2
  expr $a + $b
  ```

  The `expr` command will itself parse a string `[exec echo rm -rf $::env(HOME)] + 2`. Its evaluation will fail, but by that time, the contents of your home directory will be supposedly gone.  (Note that a kind Tcler placed `echo` in front of `rm` in a later edit to my answer in an attempt to save the necks of random copypasters, so the command as written won't call `rm` but if you remove `echo` from it, it will.)
- Double parsing inhibits certain optimisations the Tcl engine can do when dealing with calls to `expr`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, almost — ["backslash+newline" sequences are still processed even inside `{...}` blocks](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M16).

Comment: +1 really interesting read. I didn't know about this in such detail!

Comment: 'certain optimizations' like a massive speedup 80% of your code. (according to http://wiki.tcl.tk/10225 )

Comment: The longer the expression, the more the speedup.

Comment: Is there a solution for when the entire epxression including operator is in a variable e.g`set a 55
set b 66
set c "$a == $b"
expr {$c}`

Comment: @TrojanName, I think you're confused a bit. The problem has nothing to do with "the entire expression being in a variable"—rather, it's with using double-quoted strings to create the string to be put into that variable: when you do `set c "$a == $b"`, you do not get the string `$a == $b` in the variable, instead, you get `55 == 66` because the interpreter had interpolated `$a` and `$b` in `"..."`. If you'd do `set c {$a == $b}` instead, there would be no problem with doing `expr $c` directly.

Comment: Hi @kostix, thanks but I'm still confused. The output of expr in this case should be a boolean. So, I know that expr returns 1 or 0 when evaluating boolean expressions, so I would expect `expr {$c}` to return either 1 or 0. It works fine if I don't use the curlies.

Comment: @TrojanName, no this is a rather basic misunderstanding ;-) When you do `expr {$c}`, Tcl first expands those curlies, and passes the string `$c`, verbatim, as the sole argument to the command `expr`. The latter then processes that string as a script in its own mini-language and does what it says, and it basically says "perform variable expansion and return the result". Notice that it's not "perform variable expansion and interpret its result as another `expr`-script to evaluate"!

Answer (score 12):

It most certainly has security issues. In particular, it will treat the variables' contents as expression fragments rather than values, and this lets all sort of problems occur. If that's not enough, the *same* problems also totally slay performance because there is no way to generate reasonably optimal code for it: the bytecode generated will be far less efficient since all it can do is assemble the expression string and send it for a second round of parsing.

### Let's drill down to the details

```
% tcl::unsupported::disassemble lambda {{} {
    set a 1; set b 2
    puts [expr {$a + $b}]
    puts [expr $a + $b]
}}
ByteCode 0x0x50910, refCt 1, epoch 3, interp 0x0x31c10 (epoch 3)
  Source "\n    set a 1; set b 2\n    puts [expr {$a + $b}]\n    put"
  Cmds 6, src 72, inst 65, litObjs 5, aux 0, stkDepth 6, code/src 0.00
  Proc 0x0x6d750, refCt 1, args 0, compiled locals 2
      slot 0, scalar, "a"
      slot 1, scalar, "b"
  Commands 6:
      1: pc 0-4, src 5-11          2: pc 5-18, src 14-20
      3: pc 19-37, src 26-46       4: pc 21-34, src 32-45
      5: pc 38-63, src 52-70       6: pc 40-61, src 58-69
  Command 1: "set a 1"
    (0) push1 0     # "1"
    (2) storeScalar1 %v0    # var "a"
    (4) pop 
  Command 2: "set b 2"
    (5) startCommand +13 1  # next cmd at pc 18
    (14) push1 1    # "2"
    (16) storeScalar1 %v1   # var "b"
    (18) pop 
  Command 3: "puts [expr {$a + $b}]"
    (19) push1 2    # "puts"
  Command 4: "expr {$a + $b}"
    (21) startCommand +14 1     # next cmd at pc 35
    (30) loadScalar1 %v0    # var "a"
    (32) loadScalar1 %v1    # var "b"
    (34) add 
    (35) invokeStk1 2 
    (37) pop 
  Command 5: "puts [expr $a + $b]"
    (38) push1 2    # "puts"
  Command 6: "expr $a + $b"
    (40) startCommand +22 1     # next cmd at pc 62
    (49) loadScalar1 %v0    # var "a"
    (51) push1 3    # " "
    (53) push1 4    # "+"
    (55) push1 3    # " "
    (57) loadScalar1 %v1    # var "b"
    (59) concat1 5 
    (61) exprStk 
    (62) invokeStk1 2 
    (64) done
```

In particular, look at the addresses 30–34 (the compilation of `expr {$a + $b}`) and compare with addresses 49–61 (the compilation of `expr $a + $b`). The optimal code reads the values out of the two variables and just `add`s them; the unbraced code has to read the variables and concatenate with the literal parts of the expression, and then fires the result into `exprStk` which is the “evaluate an expression string” operation. (The relative number of bytecodes isn't the problem; the problem is the runtime evaluation.)

For how fundamental these differences could be, consider setting `a` to `1 || 0` and `b` to `[exit 1]`. In the case of the precompiled version, Tcl will just try to treat both sides as numbers to add (neither of which is actually numeric; you'll get an error). In the case of the dynamic version… well, can you predict it by inspection?

### So what do you do?

Optimal Tcl code should ***always*** limit the amount of runtime evaluation of expressions it performs; you can usually get it down to nothing at all unless you're doing something that takes an expression defined by the user or something like that. Where you *have* to have it, try to generate a single expression string in a variable and then just use `expr $thatVar` rather than anything more complex. If you're wanting to do adding a list of numbers (or generally applying any operator to combine them), consider using this:

```
set sum [tcl::mathop::+ {*}$theList]
```

instead of:

```
set sum [expr [join $theList "+"]]
```

(Also, *never* use a dynamic expression with `if`, `for` or `while` as that will suppress a lot of compilation.)

Remember, with Tcl it's (usually) the case that safe code is fast code. You want fast and safe code, right?

Comment: Thanks! I wish there would be a way to merge several answers into one ;-)

Comment: @kostix You wrote the answer I _would_ have written, so I had to write a different one from another perspective. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

- Without the braces, the parameters of expr are converted first to string, and then back again to numbers.
- Without braces, they are prone to injection attacks very similar to SQL injection attacks.
- You can get rounding errors you wouldn't want if you don't use braces.
- With the braces, the expressions can be compiled.

I based this on Johannes Kuhn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17281407/1578604) which was posted a while back, and you can find out in numbers, how the braced functions are more efficient on the [wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10225), along with other interesting stuff about the differences and where you can omit the braces to actually get the results you want.