# How to execute tcl script from php page and retrive the output back

Tags: php, tcl

My project requires where i need to generate a front end (php) which has all the data input fiels. And using those data as input, I need to execute a TCL script. Once the execution is done, the php page should be able to get the output of the TCL script and show it.

I have generated a sample script but not able to execute it.
can you guys please help me.

Thanks in advance

My php script is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            function print_procedure ($arg) {
                echo exec("/usr/bin/tclsh /test.tcl");
            }
            $script_name='test.tcl';
            print_procedure($script_name);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

My TCL script is:

```
set a 10
set b 20
set c [expr $a + $b]
return c
```

Comment: Consider writing everything in PHP or everything in Tcl.

Comment: Your script should put braces around the expression part of the call to `expr` — `set c [expr {$a + $b}]` — for reasons that were explained in great detail [recently](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17451671/301832)…

Comment: what is $arg @harsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tcl script should write on stdout:

```
set a 10
set b 20
set c [expr {$a + $b}]
puts $c
```

If your tcl script is supposed to output multiple lines:

e.g.:

```
puts $c
puts $c
puts $c
```

you can capture them in a PHP array:

e.g.:

```
$array = array();
function print_procedure ($arg) {
    echo exec("/opt/tcl8.5/bin/tclsh test.tcl",$array);
    //print_r($array);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. It worked and I was able to get the output onto the front end.