# Why does expr $a eq $b fail with "invalid bareword"?

Tags: tcl

I have TCL 8.6 and the following code works fine:

```
set a abc
set b abcd
if {$a eq $b} {puts hi}
```

But the following gets me error:

```
set a abc
set b abcd
expr $a eq $b

invalid bareword "abc"
in expression "abc eq abcd";
should be "$abc" or "{abc}" or "abc(...)" or ...
```

I wonder what is going on? Isn't that the condition expression in if command same as the expression in expr command?

Comment: Points to keep in mind: 1) `expr` takes one argument string and evaluates it. 2) Multiple arguments are space concatenated. 3) `expr {a eq b}` is not a valid expression, you must quotes strings, e.g.: `expr {{a} eq {b}}`

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825779/error-in-expr-command

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not the same. There is a difference between what you see, and what `expr` sees, i.e. the string that it will try to evaluate. This is because every word of the command invocation (just like with every command invocation in Tcl) is subjected to substitution before the command is executed.

First case: the braces prevent the contents of the expression from being prematurely substituted. You see `{$a eq $b}`, `expr` sees `$a eq $b`. This is two operands (`$a` and `$b`) and an operator (`eq`): `expr` can work with this.

Second case: the three arguments are substituted before they are passed to `expr`. You see `$a eq $b`, `expr` sees `abc eq abcd`. That's two nonsense values and an operator, and `expr` can't deal with that.

If there is a string that isn't a boolean value or the name of an operator in an `expr` expression, it should be part of a variable substitution (`$abc`), or the name of a function (`abc(...)`), or part of a command substitution (`[... abc ...]`), or else be explicitly quoted (`"abc"` or `{abc}`).

Always brace the arguments to `expr`. Doing so prevents many problems, this one being one of the milder.

Documentation: [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm)