# How do you review tcl bytecode in tclsh (or otherwise)

Tags: tcl, bytecode

I've seen the theory and understand the explanation why the firsst is faster than the second, but I want to see the bytecode in tcl. in the python shell, it's pretty easy to see the bytecode, but I'm having trouble finding a solution to view this in tclsh.

```
#first approach
expr {3 * 4}
#second approach
expr 3 * 4
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you got them right? The second is actually faster than the second, much much faster. You might want to read [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10225)

Comment: sorry, misordered them. Updated

Comment: Better :) Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17457051/1578604) will help a bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To look at what bytecode Tcl has generated, use `tcl::unsupported::disassemble` (assuming you've got Tcl 8.5 or later). Here's your examples:

```
% tcl::unsupported::disassemble script {expr {3 * 4}}
ByteCode 0x0x103058910, refCt 1, epoch 95, interp 0x0x100829a10 (epoch 95)
  Source "expr {3 * 4}"
  Cmds 1, src 12, inst 3, litObjs 1, aux 0, stkDepth 1, code/src 0.00
  Commands 1:
      1: pc 0-1, src 0-11
  Command 1: "expr {3 * 4}"
    (0) push1 0     # "12"
    (2) done 

% tcl::unsupported::disassemble script {expr 3 * 4}
ByteCode 0x0x1030b2f10, refCt 1, epoch 95, interp 0x0x100829a10 (epoch 95)
  Source "expr 3 * 4"
  Cmds 1, src 10, inst 14, litObjs 4, aux 0, stkDepth 5, code/src 0.00
  Commands 1:
      1: pc 0-12, src 0-9
  Command 1: "expr 3 * 4"
    (0) push1 0     # "3"
    (2) push1 1     # " "
    (4) push1 2     # "*"
    (6) push1 1     # " "
    (8) push1 3     # "4"
    (10) concat1 5 
    (12) exprStk 
    (13) done
```

As you can see, in one case Tcl has found that it has a compile-time constant and used that, and in the other case it is building an expression and firing that into the runtime expression engine (via `exprStk`, which I can tell you recursively invokes the compiler on what is *in this case* an entirely new object and so won't end up caching anything and will be expensive).

You can disassemble other things, notably `proc` (for procedures), `lambda` (for `apply` terms), and `method` (for TclOO methods; this one requires Tcl 8.6).

---

In Tcl 8.4 and earlier, it is possible to get the disassembler to print things out. You just set the global `tcl_traceCompile` variable to `2` — provided the Tcl library was built with the right configuration options, `--enable-symbols=all` is the most useful variant — and then force the code to be compiled; the disassembly (same format) gets printed straight to the real console. But this was an *awful* way to do it; 8.5 added the command version in all builds precisely to get away from that horrid mucking around with global variables. (There's also `tcl_traceExec`…)

<sup>8.6.3 will have another disassembler too, which produces output suitable for further scripting.</sup>

Comment: The command _is_ unsupported. Format likely to change at any time without notice. (But the output format has not _actually_ changed since 8.0.)

Comment: ah...thank you very much. Assuming the bytecode representation hasn't change in these simple cases much from 8.4->8.5.

Comment: What are the meanings of the headers? Mostly interested in inst, litObjs, and the stack operations, but also curious about src and code/src. Thanks again