# A follow-on to Donal about expr command performance

Tags: tcl

I just read the great reply from [Donal Fellows](https://stackoverflow.com/users/301832/donal-fellows) on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451671/why-do-tcler-suggest-to-brace-your-expressions). It is so informative.

But I have a question about this part: `never use a dynamic expression with if, for or while as that will suppress a lot of compilation.`

I read it twice, but do not think I totally get it.

Donal or others, could you elaborate it a little bit more?

[**UPDATE1**]
Out of curiosity, I tried inside tkcon the example Donal gave in his reply:

```
% set a {1||0}
1||0
% set b {[exit 1]}
[exit 1]
% expr {$a + $b}
can't use non-numeric string as operand of "+"
% expr $a + $b
1
```

Interesting, why "`expr $a + $b`" ends up "1"? Isn't "`expr $a + $b`" expanded into "`expr 1||0 + [exit 1]`"? If I just run the expanded version, tkcon just closes which makes senses to me because `[exit 1]` runs.

[**UPDATE2**] I am still pondering about my question in UPDATE1. As suggested, I did one more experiment:

```
% concat $a + $b
1||0 + [exit 1]
% expr 1||0 + [exit 1]
...tkcon closes...
```

tkcon closing is what I expected, still wondering why `expr $a + $b` yields 1.

Comment: For the **update** question, take a look at what you get if you run `concat $a + $b` (which is essentially the first step in evaluating `expr`s arguments). Then see the bit about “lazy evaluation” on the `expr` man page (the note about requiring braces doesn't apply here).

Comment: For the **update** Q, be aware that `expr $a + $b` is not at all the same as `expr {$a + $b}`. Tcl substitution rules apply, and this is a case where they matter. Also, the `+` operator only works on numbers…

Comment: `expr $a + $b` is the same as `expr [concat $a + $b]`, and so is the same (in your case) as `expr {1||0 + [exit 1]}`, but _not_ `expr 1||0 + [exit 1]`. ***THE BRACES MATTER. THE SUBSTITUTIONS MATTER.***

Answer (score 1):

You're strongly discouraged from composing expressions that way, as it is easy to get it wrong and create a (potential) security hole.

```
set x 1
set y {[exec echo >@stdout rm -rf /]};   # Assume this string has come from the user
expr $x+$y
# After Tcl language substitution, it's equivalent to this:
#     expr {1+[exec echo >@stdout rm -rf /]}
# If you're not sure why that might be a problem, think a little more...
```

It also is not strongly compiled, since Tcl's bytecode compiler does not (in general) do a lot of constant folding, and instead you get an invoke of the opcode that takes a string and *compiles that string* at runtime into bytecode for execution. It's not efficient as well as unsafe.

However, there's more. If we look at this instead:

```
if $x==$y {
    # ...
}
```

The body of that `if` is *not* compiled because the `if` compiler code is just sees the substitutions and bails out, pushing things back to (effectively) interpreted mode execution. That will slow down the whole arm of the `if`. If you *are* doing composed expressions (which I discourage for safety reasons) then at least do this:

```
if {[expr $x==$y]} {
    # ...
}
```

That at least keeps the `if` in its efficient mode. (It's otherwise semantically equivalent.)

---

### Bytecode for the above

**First, for `expr`.**

```
% tcl::unsupported::disassemble script {expr $x+$y}
ByteCode 0x0x1008b2210, refCt 1, epoch 96, interp 0x0x100829a10 (epoch 96)
  Source "expr $x+$y"
  Cmds 1, src 10, inst 12, litObjs 3, aux 0, stkDepth 3, code/src 0.00
  Commands 1:
      1: pc 0-10, src 0-9
  Command 1: "expr $x+$y"
    (0) push1 0     # "x"
    (2) loadStk 
    (3) push1 1     # "+"
    (5) push1 2     # "y"
    (7) loadStk 
    (8) strcat 3 
    (10) exprStk 
    (11) done
```

```
% tcl::unsupported::disassemble script {expr {$x+$y}}
ByteCode 0x0x1008eb610, refCt 1, epoch 96, interp 0x0x100829a10 (epoch 96)
  Source "expr {$x+$y}"
  Cmds 1, src 12, inst 8, litObjs 2, aux 0, stkDepth 2, code/src 0.00
  Commands 1:
      1: pc 0-6, src 0-11
  Command 1: "expr {$x+$y}"
    (0) push1 0     # "x"
    (2) loadStk 
    (3) push1 1     # "y"
    (5) loadStk 
    (6) add 
    (7) done
```

Note that in the first version we use `exprStk` (a general string operation) whereas the second version uses `add` (which knows it is working with numbers and throws errors otherwise).

**Then, for `if`.**

```
% tcl::unsupported::disassemble script {if $x==$y {
    incr hiya
}}
ByteCode 0x0x10095e210, refCt 1, epoch 96, interp 0x0x100829a10 (epoch 96)
  Source "if $x==$y {\n        incr hiya\n   "...
  Cmds 1, src 35, inst 17, litObjs 5, aux 0, stkDepth 4, code/src 0.00
  Commands 1:
      1: pc 0-15, src 0-34
  Command 1: "if $x==$y {\n        incr hiya\n   "...
    (0) push1 0     # "if"
    (2) push1 1     # "x"
    (4) loadStk 
    (5) push1 2     # "=="
    (7) push1 3     # "y"
    (9) loadStk 
    (10) strcat 3 
    (12) push1 4    # "\n        incr hiya\n  "...
    (14) invokeStk1 3 
    (16) done
```

```
% tcl::unsupported::disassemble script {if {[expr $x==$y]} {
    incr hiya
}}
ByteCode 0x0x10095cc10, refCt 1, epoch 96, interp 0x0x100829a10 (epoch 96)
  Source "if {[expr $x==$y]} {\n        incr hiya\n   "...
  Cmds 3, src 44, inst 32, litObjs 5, aux 0, stkDepth 3, code/src 0.00
  Commands 3:
      1: pc 0-30, src 0-43        2: pc 0-10, src 5-15
      3: pc 14-26, src 29-37
  Command 1: "if {[expr $x==$y]} {\n        incr hiya\n   "...
  Command 2: "expr $x==$y"...
    (0) push1 0     # "x"
    (2) loadStk 
    (3) push1 1     # "=="
    (5) push1 2     # "y"
    (7) loadStk 
    (8) strcat 3 
    (10) exprStk 
    (11) nop 
    (12) jumpFalse1 +17     # pc 29
  Command 3: "incr hiya"...
    (14) startCommand +13 1     # next cmd at pc 27, 1 cmds start here
    (23) push1 3    # "hiya"
    (25) incrStkImm +1 
    (27) jump1 +4   # pc 31
    (29) push1 4    # ""
    (31) done
```

Notice how the second version has understood that it is doing an increment (`incrStkImm`)? That helps a lot with performance, especially for longer, less-trivial scripts. The first version just assembles a list of arguments and uses `invokeStk1` to call the interpreted `if` implementation.

FWIW, the “gold standard” (assuming we're not in a procedure) is this:

```
% tcl::unsupported::disassemble script {if {$x==$y} {
    incr hiya
}}
ByteCode 0x0x1008efb10, refCt 1, epoch 96, interp 0x0x100829a10 (epoch 96)
  Source "if {$x==$y} {\n    incr hiya\n"...
  Cmds 2, src 29, inst 18, litObjs 4, aux 0, stkDepth 2, code/src 0.00
  Commands 2:
      1: pc 0-16, src 0-28        2: pc 9-12, src 18-26
  Command 1: "if {$x==$y} {\n    incr hiya\n"...
    (0) push1 0     # "x"
    (2) loadStk 
    (3) push1 1     # "y"
    (5) loadStk 
    (6) eq 
    (7) jumpFalse1 +8   # pc 15
  Command 2: "incr hiya"...
    (9) push1 2     # "hiya"
    (11) incrStkImm +1 
    (13) jump1 +4   # pc 17
    (15) push1 3    # ""
    (17) done
```

And for completeness, inside a procedure (well, lambda in this case, but the bytecode is identical):

```
tcl::unsupported::disassemble lambda {{} {if {$x==$y} {
    incr hiya
}}}
ByteCode 0x0x1008ecc10, refCt 1, epoch 96, interp 0x0x100829a10 (epoch 96)
  Source "if {$x==$y} {\n    incr hiya\n"...
  Cmds 2, src 29, inst 15, litObjs 1, aux 0, stkDepth 2, code/src 0.00
  Proc 0x0x102024610, refCt 1, args 0, compiled locals 3
      slot 0, scalar, "x"
      slot 1, scalar, "y"
      slot 2, scalar, "hiya"
  Commands 2:
      1: pc 0-13, src 0-28        2: pc 7-9, src 18-26
  Command 1: "if {$x==$y} {\n    incr hiya\n"...
    (0) loadScalar1 %v0     # var "x"
    (2) loadScalar1 %v1     # var "y"
    (4) eq 
    (5) jumpFalse1 +7   # pc 12
  Command 2: "incr hiya"...
    (7) incrScalar1Imm %v2 +1   # var "hiya"
    (10) jump1 +4   # pc 14
    (12) push1 0    # ""
    (14) done
```

Comment: Given the example, if $a==$b {...}, I wonder why "if" command bails out without compiling "$a==$b". According to the if command specification, the first argument is an expression, so it should just take "$a==$b" which is the first argument and compiles it, just like it is braced.

Comment: @my_question It bails out because the compiler wasn't made smart enough in that case to do otherwise. It's _rare_ that people want that sort of thing. (Sorry it's such a mundane reason…)

Comment: Got it, thanks. Could you answer my question in UPDATE2?

Comment: @my_question Your UPDATE2 indicates that you need to spend some time going back over the basic Tcl substitution semantics; you're at the point where you've found a test case where the subtleties matter.