# Why doesn't compiler automatically brace expr?

Tags: tcl, expr

I was reading through Donal Fellows' excellent explanation on why you should [brace your `expr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17457051/476388).

It makes me wonder why doesn't the tcl compiler automatically brace `{}` the `expr`? What are conditions under which this automatic bracing will fail?

Comment: See the [wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10225) under "The Art of Unbraced Expressions" where a couple of cases have been mentioned (though not all without workarounds).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It makes me wonder why doesn't the tcl compiler automatically brace `{}` the `expr`?

It actually did so during some of the alphas for 8.0. It was removed because the wider community absolutely hated it. The core Tcl language — the 12 rules on the Tcl(n) manual page — is kept extremely small and simple, and it's applied uniformly to *everything*.

No special cases. *That* is what most Tcl programmers want.

If I remember right, the auto-bracing was particularly considered for `if` and `while`. With `if`, it was because omitting the braces for a test of the result of a command was a particularly common practice with Tcl 7 because it was faster (the expression engine was rather embarrassingly slow). With `while`, it was because omitting the braces was a common user bug.

> What are conditions under which this automatic bracing will fail?

Well, it would be noticeable in something like this:

```
set a 1
set b 2
set op +
set c [expr $a$op$b]
```

Right now, that sets `c` to `3`. With auto-bracing, it would be a syntax error (since the expression grammar doesn't have anything it can do with three variables in a row). A work-around was proposed:

```
set c [eval expr $a$op$b]
```

But frankly, getting everyone to brace their expressions except when they really wanted double-substitution (and runtime expression compilation) was considered to be better.

Double-substitution is almost always an indication of a security bug, and it's always an indication of a performance problem; there's virtually always a better (faster, safer) way to do it. ***Brace your expressions.*** It's safer and faster and really easy to do: what's not to like?

Answer (score 4):

Some random thoughts on this...

- One of the strengths of the language is that evaluation is governed by a small number of rules which are applied uniformly. To have the arguments to `expr` automatically braced would mean that there would have to be an exception in the rules for this command.
- It would also mean that the interpreter would have to be rewritten, since it evaluates the arguments before it determines which command it is dealing with. The `expr` command could be renamed or aliased, making it harder for the interpreter to figure out when to autobrace.
- It would mean that if someone *wanted* double evaluation of the arguments, or wanted to construct the argument in a way that does not directly match the expression tokens, they would have to work around the automatic bracing.
- It would mean possible incompatibilities with a lot of old code.

To have the interpreter as a "back seat driver" isn't really the Tcl Way.